# Как адаптивно сверстать блок с картинкой и текстом, которые ведут себя нестандартно?

Tags: css, css3, адаптивная-верстка

Добрый день коллеги.

Помогите реализовать вот такой блок
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ГДЕ:

1. У текста есть бекграунд Текст и картинка ВИДЯТ друг друга, текст
   обтекает картинку
2. Если текста монго - он "затекает" под картинку
   (стандартный флоат), НО!!! И БЕКГРАУНД блока с текстом реагирует на
   это поведение. Красное выделение на фото.
3. Если текста МАЛО блок с текстом ужимается до определенного размера. Черное подчеркивание на  фото.

Моя попытка решения проблемы

```
[https://codepen.io/emelyanova/full/xXpbxW/][2]
```

Заранее БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО!!!!

Comment: Вот не понимаю я дизайнеров, которые из полиграфии в веб лезут. Ну ладно там идея какая-то суперкрутая, но это же просто говнище) Тут `css` не обойтись, только сильно костылить в js, по возможности советую завернуть это обратно дизайнеру.

Comment: Ну... Спасибо за моральную поддержку, конечна.))) Я так-то готова все это завернуть. Но... Хотелось и посопротивляться... Может и есть какое решение. Хотябы для случая с вырезанным бекграундом, когда много текста.)))

Comment: Так этот случай и проблемный, еще и с бордером и радиусом. тут костылить надо вплоть до svg подложки

Comment: [https://codepen.io/emelyanova/full/xXpbxW/ ] (посоветовали тут...)

Comment: Попробуйте сверстать наиболее приближенно но без костылей, а потом объяснить заказчику, что дизайнер не компетентен. Это самый правильный выход.  Заказчик же потом оставит дизайнеру хороший отзыв и он пойдет дальше рисовать свое УГ доставляя головную боль толпе верстальщиков...

Answer (score 1):

На данный момент максимально близко это вот как тут: [codepen.io/emelyanova/full/xXpbxW](http://codepen.io/emelyanova/full/xXpbxW)

Решение не мое чисто. Добрый совет опытного коллеги...

```css
@mixin breakpoint($point) {
  @media (max-width: $point) {
    @content;
  }
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  &:after,
  &:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}

.cf:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 0;
  background: transparent;
  display: block;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.modul__box {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 25px 5%;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  border-top: 3px solid #91ce07;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.celebretis {
  padding-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.celebretis__title {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: green;
}

.celebretis__descr {
  padding: 30px 5%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(221, 224, 226);
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #fafbfd;
  min-width: 70%;
  //width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.celebretis__avatar {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  max-width: 440px;
  //max-height: 300px;
  padding: 0 1em 0 0;
  float: left;
  //margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: -40px;
  @include breakpoint(600px) {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  &:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    //left: -1px;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    height: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 224, 226);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 224, 226);
    // content: '';
    // display: block;
    // width: 80%;
    // height: 30px;
    // background: #fff;
    // border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 224, 226);
    // border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 224, 226);
    @include breakpoint(600px) {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  img {
    border: 3px solid green;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="modul__box">
  <div class="celebretis cf">
    <div class="celebretis__avatar"><img src="http://farnoosh.tv/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/David-Bach.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <h3 class="celebretis__title">David Bach</h3>

    <div class="celebretis__descr">
      <p>An American writer, philosopher, and publicist: "This is a simple business that does not require special equipment. It's the perfect way for millions of people to get additional income while working on their free time without quitting their jobs."
        "The best thing about network marketing is that everything's done for you. All you need to do is find a solid company whose products and services you like and that you believe in. As soon as you find this company, it's infrastructure becomes yours.</p>
      <p>And you don't need to develop anything. They already have the facilities and the business plan. As a result, you can say that they have training, products, and services for you. It's all done for you. It's a great time saver."</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="celebretis cf">
    <div class="celebretis__avatar"><img src="http://farnoosh.tv/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/David-Bach.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <h3 class="celebretis__title">Robert Kiyosaki</h3>

    <div class="celebretis__descr">
      <p>An American businessman, investor, author of many books in self-development, pedagog, motivational speaker, and financial review writer for Yahoo Finance: "I think that the first value is very critical, which is a business education that changes
        your live. I think that this factor is the most important in making huge money in network marketing. How many people look for ways to change their lives? How many people have already grown tired of working at an exhausting job, living paycheck
        to paycheck? I recommend network marketing primarily, because it supports people who are prepared to make changes to their lives."</p>
      <p>"Most people don't live their dreams and so they say to themselves: "I can't afford that" or "I can't do that" or "I'll never be rich." In other words, they're killing their own dreams. Killing your dreams is like killing your friends. So, a large
        advantage in network marketing is that in network marketing you are surrounded by positive people that want you to have dreams. The more they help you make your dreams a reality, the faster their own dreams will. The best road to wealth is being
        a generous person. And in network marketing, you won't become rich until other people get rich."</p>
      <p>"In network marketing, unlike in regular life, you are not surrounded by negative people that constantly tell you: "You can't do it" or "What if you fail?". In network marketing, you're surrounded by people that want you to make your dreams come
        true. If you don't have dreams, then why go on living? If you don't have hope that tomorrow will be better than yesterday and the future will be better then the past, then why go on living?"</p>
      <p>"You have to ask yourself: "Will my job lead me to fulfilling my dream?" If not, then you need changes. You need to make changes to your life and join people who are following their dreams instead of being with people that kill your dream."</p>
      <p>"You can work hard in network marketing, but not be able to create your own network in one, two, or even three years. But imagine that you've brought one more person into the business. The economic strength of your network is already equating to
        four. If your network has three people, then its economic power is already equating to nine. You can never achieve that by working for a paycheck and selling your time for money. So, the economic power of working for a salary is equal to the number
        of hours you've worked. And there's not ability to multiply your efforts. Let's say that after five years in network marketing you have ten people working in your network. The economic power of your network is already equal to 100. Compare the
        economic power of 100 and 1. That's why certain network marketers are so rich. Of course, this can't be achieved in one night. This requires hard work for a certain period of time. Now let's assume that these 10 people attracted 10 more people
        into the business each -&nbsp;that's over 100 people. What is the economic power of this network? You see economic power grow exponentially."</p>
      <p>"The reason why 'networking' is such a powerful world is that it's subject to Metcalf's law. Economic power with each new person grows exponentially, not linearly. This is the huge power of networking, it's large value."</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```